# Set Date in MongoDb with MongoDate

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to store this date in my document

```
 $dateStr = strtotime("2010-01-13 00:00:00");
```

My datetime in my PHP is Europe/Rome

> date.timezone Europe/Rome Europe/Rome
>
> Default timezone  Europe/Rome
>   When I Save the document with

```
"date" => new \MongoDate($dateStr),
```

My date is

```
"data" : ISODate("2010-01-12T23:00:00.000Z"),
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB stores dates and times are in UTC and `2010-01-12T23:00:00.000Z` is the correct UTC date for your local time `2010-01-13 00:00:00`. You should convert the time back to your local time when querying the data.